# Preventing list items from appearing until YUI3 Tabview loaded

Tags: yui3, tabview

I'm using YUI 3 tabview, and my page appears without tabs very briefly, and then the tabs appear. I found this page:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/widget/
Hiding Progressively Enhanced Markup

which seems relevant, but I'm not sure how it applies to tabview.

Is there a way to prevent the display of the untabbed list until the tabs are ready?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The default style of the tab container could be set to display:none; and on your tab view creation you could then remove the display:none property
You could bind to your tabview render event and set the display on that.